# Help replacing a rotted roof overhang support post

Tags: structural, load-bearing, post, porch

We removed an old front porch deck and found that we had an old post that had rotted from the bottom that was supposed to be supporting a roof overhang. I have a temporary post up and am looking to replace it (thankfully the termites didn't make it too far up)

Running in to an issue because its an odd size - 6 x 4.5. I can't find a Simpson post base that would work for that size, and I want to make sure i raise it off the concrete this time around.

Should I stick to the same size? Could i put it on a larger concrete paver base to raise it and use 2 or 4 of these retro fit options directly on that concrete paver? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-RPBZ-ZMAX-Galvanized-Retrofit-Post-Base-for-Double-2x4-Nominal-Lumber-RPBZ/205694616

Could I just size the post down to a more normal size without potential support issues? Like a 6x6?

This was the original post wrapped in cedar:

[image: Rotten post base]

[image: Another angle of the post base]

[image: Overview of the roof, post and base]
Curious what my options are

Comment: Is the 6 x 4.5 size the overall size of the post with the decorative cedar trim, or is that the actual size of the post inside the trim? Also, you may want to pull the trim just to see what other damage there is behind it. It does look like most of the issue is right there at the bottom, but before you make plans to just fix this bottom couple of inches, it would be best to ensure that's the full extent of the problem

Comment: Thanks for the response - the size is 6 x 4.5 - with the cap it's 7.5 x 5.75 - I already removed the post and the beam above where the connection was looks great, as does the top of the post - however i'm having a termite guy out today to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's currently not doing a lot to support the overhang, it is doing *something*. Also, one would suspect that it's *supposed* to be doing a lot more.

A 2x6" board is 1.5x5.5". Making up a post out of 4 of them will give you a 6x5.5" and a trip through the table saw (or a circular saw) will reduce it to a 6x4.5". (Note: even with a table saw, it would probably be safer/easier to cut the individual boards down to size before nailing them together into a post.)

Center this on a larger post base designed for a 6x6", then trim it out around the bottom to hide the fact that the post base is bigger. You could use some more cedar for the baseboard trim since it's pretty water resistant, or you could use some PVC "wood" trim. You'll want to trim the base of the other post to match, as well. Of course, you may well want to replace the other post as a precautionary measure, or at least install a post base under it to prevent it from rotting from the ground up.

Comment: Thanks! I think this may be the way to go - I can fashion a 6 x 4.5 treated post, use the 6x6 simpson base and cap it with cedar like we did before. The new deck is going to be wrapping around the base so we don't even have to worry about what the size different looks like.

Comment: Happy to help, @James. Please take the [tour] to see the proper way of saying "thanks" 'round here.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this would be a “maintenance” project, which does not require a Building Permit if you use the same size material (posts).

However, if you change the size of the material, then a Building Permit is required.

Your top of post support is a bit unusual, as it allows face nailing connecting the top beam to the post without a metal connector. (Nice touch…a metal connector will change the appearance significantly.)

Comment: Thanks for the info - I was thinking of replacing what was there with a bigger 6x6 post now with connectors on top and bottom, but hadn't thought about needed a permit as that post looks to have been doing nothing in terms of support for quite some time. Permit would make me want to keep the original size, that process doesn't seem like it would be fun.

Comment: Whether a building permit is required or not would be location dependent. I doubt that this project would require one in most jurisdictions. Even if it was, there is no way I would get one for this.